# Passing parameters in lambda expression for Action parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm writing a method and trying to straighten out my understanding of C# lambda expressions. Bellow is a call to my background update method. It runs its task downloading each file and calling the provided Action in lambda expression form as depicted below.

```
 await BackgroundDownload((ParamOne, ParamTwo) => {
     // Update file downloaded count
     // Update file progress bar                   
 });
```

My struggle figuring this out is how do I provide parameters to my Action in a lambda expression as shown above such that I can refer to them in my code?

EDIT:

Method I declared:

```
public static async Task BackgroundDownload(Action<int, int> progressUpdate)
```

This method then calls:

```
progressUpdate(itemsToDownload.Count, (int)(current * 100 / response.ContentLength));
```

Comment: If you want the parameters to be references then they have to be classes and not structs.

Comment: I actually mean how can I refer to my paramaters in my lambda expression and the satisfy the requirements of the Action paramater for my method

Comment: you can just use the `ParamOne` and `ParamTwo` inside the {}  of BackgroundDownload which will probably be the count for ParamOne and A Percentage of the second `(int)(current * 100 / response.ContentLength)`

Comment: When you create the lambda you name the parameters. `(p1, p2) => { Console.WriteLine(p1 * p2);}` and you just use them.  And you would use your `Action` like it's a function.

Comment: `progressUpdate` should probably be [`IProgress<ProgressReport>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx), where `ProgressReport` is `struct { int Count; int Percentage; }`. [`IProgress<T>` is the standard way of reporting progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#progress-reporting-optional).

Answer (score 1):

Just use variable in lambda expression.

```
await BackgroundDownload((ParamOne, ParamTwo) => {
 Console.WriteLine("File downloaded:" + ParamOne);
 Console.WriteLine("File progress:" + ParamTwo);
```

});

Or create method

```
public static void UpdateResult(int filesCount, int fileProgress)
{
  //Update Progress
}
```

And use it instead lambda

```
await BackgroundDownload(UpdateResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name them as normally.

If the method is defined as:

```
public void executeAction(Action<int, int> action) { }
```

You can create a lambda action with named parameters like the following:

```
int c;
executeAction((int a, int b) => { c = a + b; });
```

Or in your case it would be something like

```
await BackgroundDownload((int count, int progress) => {
    // Update file downloaded count
    this.FileCount = count;
    // Update file progress bar                   
    this.Progress = progress;
});
```

With the lamba expression, you have the same scope as the method where the lambda expression is called.